# ZFS reporting different disk usage, which one is correct?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, zfs, zfsonlinux

I am trying to figure out how much space on disk is used by ZFS, with deduplicaiton eabled.
I have only enabled deduplication, not changed chunk size or anything else. 
But depending on the command I run, I get different usages reported for my pool I logically has called `zfs`. 
The total size of my data corpus in a standard EXT4 is 720GB.

- `zfs list` gives: 672GB used
- `zfs get -Hp used zfs` gives: 721962885120 (BYTES) ~ 722GB
- `zpool list` gives: 423GB used

`zpool` also shows a deduplication ratio of 1.59x, which is pretty cool. 
The amount given by `zpool` correlates with the deduplication ratio. 
But why then does the `zfs list` and `zfs get` report something else and what should I trust? 
I have been reading the documentation, but it is not clear to me which one is the correct one.

If it matters I am running ZFS on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I would try to calculate the used disk size the other way around: `(Total disc/volume size) - (free disk space)`. That would be the effective used size.

Comment: eh? So why not use used?

Comment: Because as you already have observed the specification what is "used" can quite differ, is it only file data with or without meta data, ZFS internal data, journaling, ... Therefore my suggestion to follow the "KISS" (keep it simple and stupid) approach.